# Как исправить ошибку при установке selenium?

Tags: python, debian, selenium, chromium

Kод selenium + python:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
browser.get('http://seleniumhq.org/')
```

Exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 79
```

Hа сервере c ОС debian, пробовал сносить chromium и ставить заново, но не помогло.

P.S.:
После установки 79 версии появился такой трейсбек:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tele.py", line 82, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "/home/dir/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 394, in polling
    self.__non_threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
  File "/home/dir/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 445, in __non_threaded_polling
    self.__retrieve_updates(timeout)
  File "/home/dir/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 280, in __retrieve_updates
    self.process_new_updates(updates)
  File "/home/dir/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 317, in process_new_updates
    self.process_new_messages(new_messages)
  File "/home/dir/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 336, in process_new_messages
    self._notify_next_handlers(new_messages)
  File "/home/dir/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 1470, in _notify_next_handlers
    self._exec_task(handler["callback"], message, *handler["args"], **handler["kwargs"])
  File "/home/dir/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 467, in _exec_task
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "tele.py", line 46, in load_photo
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/dir/chromedriver')
  File "/home/dir/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/home/dir/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/dir/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 177, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "/home/dir/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/dir/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=79.0.3945.36 (3582db32b33893869b8c1339e8f4d9ed1816f143-refs/branch-heads/3945@{#614}),platform=Linux 4.9.0-12-amd64 x86_64)
```

Comment: ставь `Chrome version 79`

Comment: Как? есть ли такая версия в открытом доступе? я искал и пытался разными способами установить, но не смог

Comment: Вместо спасибо, нажмите галочку oколо ответа.

Comment: та же ошибка. поставил .deb пакет 79 версии, а google-chrome-stable выдает 83 версию

Comment: несвязанный новый вопрос здесь принято задавать отдельно, а не вносить правки в уже существующий вопрос, на который к тому же уже дали исчерпывающий ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 79
```

Текст ошибки весьма информативен: ставьте Chrome 79.